# How I can speed up this query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a active record query

```
Catalog::Product.joins(:product_properties).where("catalog_product_properties.name != ''").uniq.count
```

he generate this sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "catalog_products"."id") FROM "catalog_products" INNER JOIN "catalog_product_properties" ON "catalog_product_properties"."catalog_product_id" = "catalog_products"."id" WHERE (catalog_product_properties.name != '')
```

who execute ~ 1.8 second

I try to rewrite this, and I have this

```
Catalog::Product.connection.select_all("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT catalog_products.id FROM catalog_products INNER JOIN catalog_product_properties ON catalog_product_properties.catalog_product_id = catalog_products.id WHERE (catalog_product_properties.name != '')) AS temp")
```

who execute about ~ 1 second, but it is still too long.Both tables have about 200k records, how I can speed up?

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "catalog_products"."id")
FROM "catalog_products" INNER JOIN
     "catalog_product_properties"
      ON "catalog_product_properties"."catalog_product_id" = "catalog_products"."id"
WHERE (catalog_product_properties.name != '')
```

Doesn't need the `join` (assuming proper foreign key relationships).  It can be written as:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "catalog_products_properties"."catalog_product_id")
FROM "catalog_product_properties"
WHERE (catalog_product_properties.name <> '')
```

This query, in turn, can benefit from an index on `catalog_product_properties(name, catalog_product_id)`.

Alas, I'm not familiar with Ruby, but this should not be very hard to express.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, it is good solution.But this query execute a same as my query above :) 1 second.I thought impossible make a speedy query

Answer (score 0):

You should write it as:

```
Catalog::ProductProperty.where("catalog_product_properties.name != ''").count(:catalog_product_id, distinct: true)
```